# Wifi requires rmmod and modprobe commands

Tags: kernel-modules

For some months now, I have had to run

```
rmmod bcma wl && modprobe wl
```

after booting to get my wifi to work on my Macbook Air from 2012.
The network card is Broadcom's BCM43224.  I'm using Arch and the
broadcom-wl-dkms driver.

I tried to blacklist bcma using the methods described in

```
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_module#Blacklisting
```

but this had no effect.  (And, since `rmmod bcma` gave no error, I
suppose the module was not successfully blacklisted.)

So: how do I get my wifi to work without having to issue that command after booting?

Comment: Use `modprobe -rv` instead of `rmmod` to get more verbosity.